# Http.get local file VS url

Tags: angularjs, json, http-get

I want to load a JSON file and draw a table with angular.
It works when i use this line :

> $http.get("datatest3.txt")

But once I use the url instead "http://www.floatrates.com/daily/eur.json", while the content is the exact same JSON data,
it does not work.

Does someone know why ?

Comment: Because, unless www.floatrates.com allows requests from a domain other than floatrates.com, AJAX requests from a domain other that floatrates.com may not get resources from floatrates.com, for security reasons. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: What error you are getting in console ?

Comment: the console : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.floatrates.com/daily/eur.json. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).